# CSS won't load with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: servlets, utf-8

trying for several days now to get my webapp to accept UTF-8 encoded requests. I'm out of ideas how to get that going.

Setup:
  - DigitalOcean Droplet (Debian)
  - Tomcat Container (8.5.43)
  - JavaServlet Webapp

What i already did:
 - set the locale at my Droplet to de_AT.UTF-8
 - set the tomcat config to use UTF-8 for every request on 8080 via config.xml

```
  ...
  <Connector port=8080 ... URIEncoding="UTF-8" ...>
  ...
```

- implemented a CharSetFilter, that is used for every request (web.xml holds the /* mapping for that filter). Code of the Filter:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        next.doFilter(request, response);

    }
```

- set the encoding on every jsp file with

```
<%@page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
```

- set the encoding on every html with

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

- set the encoding in the css with

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

- use UTF-8 in eclipse as encoding before exporting to WAR

The CSS does not get loaded although it is referencable via the link in the browser-inspector.

I have deployed it so you can take a look at it:
http://2foliant.tk

Can anyone PLEASE help me out and tell me, why the CSS won't get loaded?

Comment: I suggest to remove the servlet filter and try . Can you post your compiled jsp page which contains a reference to css file if you can

Comment: REALLY? I removed the filter and it works.... WHY? Got this hint from this source: https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-utf-8
THX A LOT Alan. This almost drove me crazy.

btw: how can i mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the filter and see the result 
Please remove the css tag since it is not related to css problem 
Great to hear it is sorted

Accept this as a correct answer if you can do that

Comment: OK. i was a bit too enthusiastic yesterday. I was so happy, the filename got transmitted correct, that i did not recognize, that the other formfields are not. So still kind of the same problem. The "äöüß" in input type="text" fields come to the servlet as "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã". Any further suggestions?

I have the accept-charset="utf-8" in the form tag...

Comment: It's me again... Added my Filter again, but only specifically for every form-submitting url. Now all seems to work. I have to say: it is really horrible how we have to handle such a basic requirement... solved (again)...

Comment: Good to hear that.